# Something similar to The Knowledge Argument which works within Physicalism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, knowledge, physicalism, experience

[Here is The Knowledge Argument according to SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge) (*Mary is either monochrome or views the world through monochrome monitor*):

> (1) Mary has all the physical information concerning human color vision before her release.

> (2) But there is some information about human color vision that she does not have before her release.

> Therefore

> (3) Not all information is physical information.

What I want is something like:

1. Mary has all the physical information concerning human color vision before her release *possible to her physical biology*
2. But there is some information about human color vision that she does not have before her release. *(Same as original, which should follow necessarily from 1.)*

Therefore:

3. Mary can't know sans experiencing color all there is to know about vision

From the same SEP there's a precursor to The Knowledge Argument, "knowledge intuition: the intuition that no amount of knowledge of the physical information or physical facts concerning certain experiences can by itself suffice for knowledge of what these experiences are like, i.e., knowledge of their qualitative character or distinctive qualia". This precursor seems almost workable within physicalism. If we admit experience is physical and admit hard limits to physical processes, then it seems physicalism can subsume it.

All creatures are biologically and physically limited, limiting knowing *everything*. The precusor is talking about some lofty, unphysical entity without physical limitation. Limits like the speed of light, black hole mass density, information density, possessing cone cells, etc limit any creature's capabilities. Therefore, not all physical processes nor physical knowledge are universally accessible to every creature at every time. It may take Mary having cones implanted to know color. She can't approach it from her current physical makeup.

Are there any major pitfalls to this? Is this workable within physicalism?

Comment: Physicalists do not care what physical limitations do or do not allow creatures to access. They are realists so for them what is is there regardless. They dispute that extra-physical "information" exists in principle, this is packaged into Mary for greater perspicuity, and the limitations are ignored for the sake.

Comment: The basic issue here is experience/qualia.  We have experiences, and they are different from the activation of sensors.  Sensor activation == experience is an Identity Theory claim which is readily falsified by test.  So no, this approach will not work.  Basically, you seem to be trying to avoid thinking about qualia and experience.  This has a long history among physicalists -- see the half century of trying to do psychology while ignoring consciousness, but it is widely seen as a misguided and intrinsically ineffective "solution".

Comment: The Mary thought problem was designed to address a different version of Identity Theory, a functional version of Identity, where function/information == consciousness.  The idea was that Mary can do the function of color study, but that is different form the experience of qualia, hence functional identity is also refuted by test.  By translating from function to information, there are possible issues to poke at in our understanding of "information", that possibly make this an imperfect thought problem. But it is also widely accepted that Functional IT is also refuted by this and similar tests.

Comment: @Conifold I there a theory of mind that accounts for physical limitations while being a physicalist?

Comment: @Dcleve If functionalism is, doing all the same functions gives rise to the same experience , then I think it doesn’t fully apply to my question. I’m saying Mary can’t be functionally equivalent to ColorMary because they are not doing the same functions due to physical differences/limitations.

Comment: @JKusin -- There are a lot of problems with neural Identity Theory.  An identity doesn't work when our neurology self-modifies all the time, yet we seem to have the same thought over time.  Also, logical neural identity would not allow communication to someone with even microscopically different neurology -- much less to a different species.  This issue is multiple realizability, and drove the switch to functionalism.  Functionalism also welcomed behaviorists, who realized that things like "theory of other minds" aren't behavioral, but can be functional.

Comment: Neural Identity of experience to sensor actuation has both positive and negative refutations.  One can look and have cones active, but our mind far away thinking about say a  relationship issue.  IE no experience despite active sensors.  Also, my eyes could be destroyed in a brutal accident, so no cones, but I can still imagine color (experience despite no cones).  For EVERY proposed Identity, there are refuting test cases.  Identity Theory today is therefore that some TBD additional but still undefined criteria is also needed.  This makes it basically an untestable ideology, not science.

Comment: @Dcleve I agree those are valid criticisms of identity theory. I will have to dig deeper to learn more, thanks. I guess I see the gap between atoms and identity as SO great, so many levels of emergence, (but still physical) that these issues can be explained one day. But it is not current science and needs to be explained.

Comment: I think your comment on different functions is correct -- but most philosophers disagree.  Jaegwon Kim agrees that the various thought problems that challenge functionalism show that qualia do not reduce to functions, but physicalists like him assert the physical is causally closed, so non-physical qualia cannot then DO functions.  But we can ask Mary -- "is this new" and she will say "yes", which is pretty clearly both physically causal and functional outcome from qualia.  Yes, there are functional differences, but this is resisted based on the prior assumptions of physicalism.

Comment: Sure, but that's more of a subject for biophysics and empirical psychology for physicalists.

Comment: @JKusin -- Physicalists today are a little uncertain on emergence and non-reductivity, and IT.  Most now say they are non-reductive emergent physicalists, and befog Identity Theory by asserting a vague "supervenience" relationship to avoid identity falsifications while effectively assuming supervenience is equivalent to identity.  The principles of emergence, and rules for causal interaction between tiers of structures, are currently unknown.  This IS the most plausible path for physicalists, but physicalists then denying that consciousness can be emergent or casual no longer makes sense.

Comment: @JKusin -- physicalist leaning "naturalists" are gradually approaching Karl Popper's view of consciousness emerging from matter, and abstract objects actually existing.    There is some but not a lot of difference today between Popper's emergent dualism and emergent physicalism.  Popper's views pass the "testable" criteria that naturalists should hold themselves too (supervenience does not), and also PASSES the sorts of tests I describe.  Popper's opus on this is The Self and Its Brain, if you want to explore his views